# Output a dataframe using foldLeft on an existing dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe which I want to apply aggregate functions using `foldLeft` (or any other method) to each column. The aggregate functions applied to the column will depend on the dataType of the column.

Note that since I will be working with a large dataframe, I do not want to use `.collect()` or anything that writes a lot of things into the driver.

The initial dataframe looks like the following:

```
+----------------+-----------------+------------------+
| id(StringType) | lat(DoubleType) | long(DoubleType) |
+----------------+-----------------+------------------+
| ID1            | 10.2            | 20.1             |
| ID2            | 11.1            | 50.1             |
| ID3            | null            | null             |
+----------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

For this example, I want to compute count of nulls for all dataTypes, only compute mean for `DoubleType`, and only compute cardinality for `StringType` columns.

Here is the skeletal code I have that implements `foldLeft` but it might not be the right way.

```
def ourMethod(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val columns = df.schema.fields
  val initDf = spark.emptyDataFrame
  columns.foldLeft(...)((tempDf, column) => {
    column match {
      case StructField(name, dataType, _, _) => {
        dataType match {
          case StringType => ... //something like df.select("column").approx_count_distinct(), though writes in driver.
          case DoubleType => ... //something like df.agg(avg(column))
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

The expected output looks like the following:

```
+----------+---------+-------+-------------+
| col_name | is_null | mean  | cardinality |
+----------+---------+-------+-------------+
| id       |       0 | null  | 3           |
| lat      |       1 | 10.65 | null        |
| long     |       1 | 35.1  | null        |
+----------+---------+-------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if `foldLeft` helps here but it is definitely doable. Given data frame

```
val df =
  Seq(("ID1", Some(10.2), Some(20.1)),
      ("ID2", Some(11.1), Some(50.1)),
      ("ID3", None, None))
    .toDF("id", "lat", "lon")
```

we can take a couple of approaches.

1. Programmatically create the aggregate functions. Quite straightforward

```
val aggs = df.schema.fields.flatMap {
  case StructField(name, DoubleType, _, _) =>
    Seq(max(col(name).isNull) as s"${name}_is_null",
        mean(col(name)) as s"${name}_mean")
  case StructField(name, StringType, _, _) =>
    Seq(max(col(name).isNull) as s"${name}_is_null",
        max(length(col(name))) as s"${name}_cardinality")
}

df.agg(aggs.head, aggs.tail: _*).show()
```

However, the output will be in one line and not exactly what was asked. Of course this single row can be e.g. collected to the driver and modified or flat-mapped to the desired format. This is the unprocessed output:

```
+----------+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+--------+
|id_is_null|id_cardinality|lat_is_null|          lat_mean|lon_is_null|lon_mean|
+----------+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+--------+
|     false|             3|       true|10.649999999999999|       true|    35.1|
+----------+--------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+--------+
```

2. Exploding the rows to a format where the row name is a column that can be used for grouping and possible values are wrapped in nullable fields. This works as `null` values are omitted from aggregations

```
case class FlatRow(name: String, d: Option[Double], s: Option[String])

df.flatMap { row: Row =>
    row.schema.fields.zipWithIndex.map {
      case (StructField(name, DoubleType, _, _), index) =>
        FlatRow(name,
                if (row.isNullAt(index)) None
                else Some(row.getDouble(index)),
                None)
      case (StructField(name, StringType, _, _), index) =>
        FlatRow(name,
                None,
                if (row.isNullAt(index)) None
                else Some(row.getString(index)))
    }
  }
  .groupBy($"name")
  .agg(max($"d".isNull && $"s".isNull) as "is_null",
       mean($"d") as "mean",
       max(length($"s")) as "cardinality")
  .show()
```

A bit more code but it outputs the format that was asked:

```
+----+-------+------------------+-----------+
|name|is_null|              mean|cardinality|
+----+-------+------------------+-----------+
| lat|   true|10.649999999999999|       null|
| lon|   true|              35.1|       null|
|  id|  false|              null|          3|
+----+-------+------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The second method is especially useful. As a followup, is it possible to have an empty default case that ignores the column (i.e will not be added into the output dataframe) if the data type is not Double or String?

Comment: @igeass Yes, probably easiest to use `collect` so a small change `row.schema.fields.zipWithIndex.map` -> `row.schema.fields.zipWithIndex.collect` should do the trick